# How to remove extender from an existing observable?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-extensions

I am using the Knockout Validation plugin and setting an observable as required using the extender:

```
myObservable.extend({required:true});
```

Is it possible for me to remove the extender after adding it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can remove all the validation relates properties form an observable which were added by the ko validation with calling:

```
myObservable.extend({validatable: false});
```

Or if you want to only remove the required validation you can remove it from the `rules` collection:

```
myObservable.rules.remove(function (item) {
        return item.rule == "required";
    });
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7deMr/).

But the ko validation has support for [conditional validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation), so you can specify some condition when the validation should work so maybe this is what you need:

```
myObservable.extend({
    required: {
        message: "Some message",
        onlyIf: function () { return //some condition; }
    }
});
```

Comment: the onlyIf was exactly what I needed, but how about what I asked about removing the extender? Is that supported by knockout?

Comment: No, you cannot remove an extender unless the extender itself provides a way to "revert" its own changes. In the case of the ko validation the `myObservable.extend({validatable: false});` call exactly does this it removes all the the validation related stuff which was added by `.extend({required:true});` or any of the other rules.

Answer (score 2):

[nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) answer works with a small typo correction - the function in the remove(...) call should return a boolean value (i.e. '==' instead of '='):

> ```
> myObservable.rules.remove(function(item) {
>   return item.rule == "required";
> });
> ```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhevg7tn/)