# How to remove the validation rules [extenders] from observable in Knockout Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

[How to remove extender from an existing observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120416/how-to-remove-extender-from-knocout-observable)

I tried the above link & can make the observable NOT validatable. But if the check the observable with **ko.validation.utils.isValidatable()** function, it gives me TRUE [it says observable is validatable even after making that as NOT validatable].

Because making **validatable:true** leaves the isValid, isModified, isValidating observables & error variable on the observable property.

Please help me to remove the validation **completely** form the observable property.

Comment: Can you put up an example on JSFiddle? From what I see in Knockout-Validation's source, `.extend({validatable: false})` should work perfectly.

Comment: Actually what I've answered in the other question still should work. So using `validatable: false` on an observalbe `yourObservable.extend({validatable: false})` should remove all the validation related properties. However there is currently **bug** in KO validation and the  **`validatable: false` only works in you are using the DEBUG version of knockout**. Here is a working JSFiddle using the latest version of KO validation and the DEBUG version of knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/6d5NY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the onlyIf param if you want to toggle the validation. completly remove validation is not built in, check my question here for a way

[Move validation from observable to computed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119826/move-validation-from-observable-to-computed)