# Validatable true not working in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation, knockout-3.0

i want to make a textbox required via knockout.js
what i want is 
1.- Click a radiobutton(value 1) = TextboxAutor not required
2.- Click a radiobutton(value 2) = TextboxAutor required

in my Code from default i have
self.Author = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

when im trying to use  self.Author .extend({ validatable: false });
via a button, it works, but when i try to use validatable : true

is not working, is there a way to make an observable required true again ?
also i'm using the latest version of ko.js and ko.validation.js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120416/how-to-remove-extender-from-an-existing-observable

Comment: @Bludev Yeah i can remove the validatable, but the problem is, after i remove it  i can't add the required again.

Comment: 1.- Click radiobuttton(with value 1) to Remove (.extend({ validatable: false })) . 
2.- Click radiobutton(with value 2) to Add (.extend({ validatable: TRUE })) this is not working